# Passsing a value to a method using a custom attribute

Tags: c#, reflection, invoke, custom-attributes

I'm trying to understand how can I use custom attributes to call method passing a parameters

```
    [ExecuteMe("hello", "reflection")]
    public void M3(string s1, string s2)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("M3 s1={0} s2={1}", s1, s2);
    }
```

I'm trying to call this method using this code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    { 
        var assembly= Assembly.LoadFrom("MyLibrary.dll");

        foreach (var type in assembly.GetTypes())
        {
            object act = Activator.CreateInstance(type);

            var  methodInfos = type.GetMethods().Where(m => m.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(ExecuteMe)).Any());
            foreach (var mInfo in methodInfos)
            {
                //Console.WriteLine(mInfo.Name);
                var argument =  mInfo.GetParameters();

                foreach (var a in argument)
                {

                    Console.WriteLine(a);
                   // a.RawDefaultValue;
                   mInfo.Invoke(act, new object[]{a});
                }


            }


            if (type.IsClass)
                Console.WriteLine(type.FullName);

        }
        Console.ReadLine();

    }
```

It doesn't work because "a" is a ParameterInfo and invoke want a Object[].
What am I doing wrong and how do I get those values?

this is my attribute:

```
public class ExecuteMe : Attribute
{
    public object[] args;

    public ExecuteMe(params object[] _args)
    {

            this.args = _args;

    }
}`
```

Comment: You never actually access the `args` member of the attribute you have found. Maybe you should start by printing that to the console.

Comment: Sorry can you be a little more specific?

Answer (score 0):

To make sure I understand what you're trying to do, if a method has an `ExecuteMe` attribute, you want to call the method, passing the arguments from the attribute to the method?

I'm going to assume that this is just for experimentation and you already realize that this doesn't guarantee whether the number or type of arguments supplied to the attribute will match the number and type of arguments the method requires. The attribute takes an unlimited number of objects, while the method requires two strings.

The issue that you're seeing is that you're looking at `.GetParameters` which doesn't tell you anything about the values coming from the attribute. It just describes what the parameters of the method are.

What you need is to get the `args` property from the attribute and pass those values when you invoke the method.

Just for the sake of illustration I'm going to use a method where the signatures match.

```
public class ClassWithMethod
{
    [ExecuteMe("hello", "reflection")]
    public void M3(params object[] args)
    {
        var strings = args.Where(arg => arg != null).Select(arg => arg.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", strings));
    }

    // Just to verify that we're only invoking methods with the attribute.
    public void MethodWithoutAttribute() { }
}
```

...and in the console app I'm going to read types from the executing assembly just for convenience.

I rearranged a few things but you'll see what's going on:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();

    foreach (var type in assembly.GetTypes())
    {
        var methodInfos = type.GetMethods();

        // looking at all the methods, not yet narrowing it down to those
        // with the attribute.
        foreach (var mInfo in methodInfos)
        {
            // We don't just want to know if it has the attribute.
            // We need to get the attribute.
            var executeMeParameter = mInfo.GetCustomAttribute<ExecuteMe>();

            // If it's null the method doesn't have the attribute. 
            // Ignore this method.
            if (executeMeParameter == null) continue;

            // We don't need to create the instance until we know that we're going
            // to invoke the method.
            object act = Activator.CreateInstance(type);

            // Pass the args property of the attribute (an array of objects)
            // as the argument list for the method.
            mInfo.Invoke(act, new object[]{executeMeParameter.args});
        }

        if (type.IsClass)
            Console.WriteLine(type.FullName);
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

In this case we're just passing all of the arguments from the attribute. This is the part where it's a little messy. What if `args` had three string values but the method had a single `int` parameter?

This part is a little weird. I had to do this because of the `params` keyword.

```
mInfo.Invoke(act, new object[]{executeMeParameter.args});
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

---

Another reason why I'm assuming that this is just for experimentation is that if you wanted to use an attribute to determine which method to run and to pass in hard-coded parameters (which itself is something I can't see doing), this would be much easier:

```
[ExecuteMe]
public void CallM3()
{
    M3("Hello", "reflection");
}

public void M3(params object[] args)
{
    var strings = args.Where(arg => arg != null).Select(arg => arg.ToString());
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", strings));
}
```

...and the attribute has no arguments:

```
public class ExecuteMe : Attribute
{
}
```

The difference now is that everything is strongly typed and compiles. You don't have to worry about whether the parameters will match up at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

I've rewritten it a little. You never actually accessed the arguments you gave to your attribute.

```
namespace StackOverflow
{
    using System;
    using System.Reflection;

    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method, Inherited = false, AllowMultiple = true)]
    public class ExecuteMe : Attribute
    {
        public object[] Arguments { get; }

        public ExecuteMe(params object[] args)
        {
            this.Arguments = args;
        }
    }

    public class TestSubject
    {
        [ExecuteMe(5, "Hello")]
        [ExecuteMe(7, "World")]
        public int Function(int i, string s)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Executing TestSubject.Function with parameters {0} and {1}", i, s);

            return 42;
        }
    }

    internal static class Program
    {
        internal static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // This could come from another dll, for example
            // var assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom("MyLibrary.dll").GetTypes();
            var availableTypes = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().ExportedTypes;

            foreach (var type in availableTypes)
            {
                foreach (var method in type.GetMethods())
                {
                    foreach (var attribute in method.GetCustomAttributes<ExecuteMe>())
                    {
                        var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(type);

                        method.Invoke(instance, attribute.Arguments);
                    }
                }
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

This should yield:

[image]